# Code Academy (Python) code doesn't actually run in PyCharm. Can someone explain?

Tags: python, function, class, self

Here is the code that "worked" in the Code Academy tutorial "TakingAVacation":

```
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475

def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140*nights

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = days*40
    if days>=7:
        cost -= 50
    elif days>=3:
        cost -= 20
    return cost

def trip_cost(city,days,spending_money):
    return rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + spending_money

print trip_cost("Los Angeles", 5, 600)
```

However, this didn't work when I tried to run it in PyCharm. I'm using Python 3 and the tutorial is using Python 2, but classes are at the end so I put this into a Python Script:

```
__author__ = 'Kvothealar'

class TakingAVacation:

    def plane_ride_cost(city):
        if city == "Charlotte":
            return 183
        elif city == "Tampa":
            return 220
        elif city == "Pittsburgh":
            return 222
        elif city == "Los Angeles":
            return 475

    def hotel_cost(nights):
        return 140*nights

    def rental_car_cost(days):
        cost = days*40
        if days>=7:
            cost -= 50
        elif days>=3:
            cost -= 20
        return cost

    def trip_cost(city, days, spending_money):
        return rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + spending_money

    print(trip_cost("Los Angeles", 5, 600))
```

It is giving me an error that "rental_car_cost" is undefined. Is there some problem by using these functions within a class? Also I've been told I should be using "self" as the first argument in each of these functions. How should I be calling the functions if the first argument is "self". I was getting errors when I tried that too.

Comment: This seems like two questions. "Why isn't this first code block working in Pycharm?" and "Why is the class in this second code block giving me an error?". It may be worthwhile to make separate posts for each one.

Comment: FWIW, the first code block runs fine for me when I execute it from the command line.

Comment: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,  `self` is needed for a member function to refer to another member function in the same class. Another mistake is that those member functions are not static, so you have to make an instance of `TakingAVacation` before calling its member function.

```
class TakingAVacation:
    def plane_ride_cost(self, city):
        if city == "Charlotte":
            return 183
        elif city == "Tampa":
            return 220
        elif city == "Pittsburgh":
            return 222
        elif city == "Los Angeles":
            return 475

    def hotel_cost(self, nights):
        return 140*nights

    def rental_car_cost(self, days):
        cost = days*40
        if days>=7:
            cost -= 50
        elif days>=3:
            cost -= 20
        return cost

    def trip_cost(self, city, days, spending_money):
        return self.rental_car_cost(days) + self.hotel_cost(days) + self.plane_ride_cost(city) + spending_money

holiday = TakingAVacation()
print(holiday.trip_cost("Los Angeles", 5, 600))
```